# In android app making packages are not importing

Tags: java, android, import

when I pasted the import statements in android studio, they are not importing. I mean when I pasted just like a flash they are disappearing.

Comment: Disappearing? Is it really disappearing? Like how?

Comment: Where are you pasting them?

Comment: when I pasted or typed on editor in android studio after 1 second they are not visible again i done again disappearing

Comment: What's your actual issue? Are you not able to reference some packages you need to use in your code? Does your code compile?

Comment: yes they are not invoking

Answer (score 0):

Use a instance or a member from the imported class first, then import the class. I don't know why it does this, probably to avoid imports that are not needed. Also you may notice that some classes are imported automatically when you use the class , GLSurfaceView for example.